# imagemagick convert throws error while installing through binary

Tags: imagemagick-convert

When trying to build `ImageMagick-7.0.8-36` from source on `Ubuntu 18.01` I'm getting the following error

> (coders/heic.c:564:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to
>   type ‘struct heif_error’ from type ‘int’
>   error=heif_context_add_XMP_metadata(ctx,image_handle,..):

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt build-dep imagemagick
$ wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ cd ImageMagick-7.0.8-36
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Comment: did you able to install previous version?

Comment: yes, but didnt work